# How to add RXTX serial API's javadoc to eclipse or netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I tried to add the exteranl javadoc from project properties --> libraries --> javadoc location. 
I tried both local directory, ...\RXTX_example\documentation\public or from http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/doc/index.html in eclipse.
But neither of them gives a correct result and it only shows a note: The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Try `http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/doc/` (i.e. without the `index.html`) as the location. This worked for me in Eclipse (but for another library).

Comment: Thanks. However,it turns out that rxtx javadoc is empty doc. I added a local copy of java communication api doc which I download from sun, but eclipse says it is looking for a "package list" file which is not listed.

Comment: The URL I gave contains a [package-list](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/doc/package-list), containing only one package `gnu.io`. The Java Communications API is in the package `javax.comm`. You can't use the documentation for one of them for the other (even if they have the same class names inside these packages).